# Max eden space size in caffeine cache

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

Is there a way to configure the maximum eden space size in caffeine cache? If not, what is the default size? https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/sketch/WindowTinyLfuPolicy.java

Comment: What does this have to do with Guava?

Comment: @AndyTurner, sorry, I couldn't find a tag for the "caffeine" library.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the confusion is my prior involvement with Guava and Caffeine's similarities. Kevin has said he favors transitioning Google over to Caffeine after the JDK8 release, but I think how the relationship will evolve is still an unknown.

Answer (score 2):

The term `eden` was borrowed from JVM generational garbage collectors, where most objects die young and are not promoted. We later decided on `window` when coming up with a name for the eviction policy (`Window TinyLFU`).

In the [simulator](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Simulator) you can adjust the window size by modifying the `percent-main` in the [configuration file](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L171). That makes it easy to experiment with different trace files when evaluating policies and the impact of tuning options.

For the production facing cache, the window size is not a configuration parameter. This value is hard coded to 1%, which was near optimal across a variety of workloads and avoids TinyLFU's degredation scenarios. In some workloads (OLTP disk traces) a larger value has a small gain, but not enough to expose a configuration option. Doing so wouldn't carry its conceptual weight by confusing most users and leak implementation details.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @andrsncpr I work right by the Caltrain station near Amplitude, so feel free to email me if you play around and want to grab lunch to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

you can add eden space declaration at the start of JVM using the parameters:

-XX:NewSize=size

-XX:MaxNewSize=size

Ideally Eden space = 3/8 total heap size.